# Running java programs from the command line on Windows 10

Tags: java, command-line, windows-10

I'm trying to run a basic "Hello World" app from the command line on windows 10 using

```
javac MyFirstProgram.java
```

but i receive

```
'javac' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch
```

naturally, the first thing i did was google the problem and many solutions were presented, tried a few but nothing worked, has anybody else experienced this?

Comment: You need to add the location of your JDK to your PATH variable, if you wish to call javac.exe without the path. Or, you can simply call it via the full path to javac.exe from your JDK installation.

Comment: Either provide the full path to javac, something like `"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\javac"` or add the path to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: You need to update the PATH environment variable, as is described in the [JDK installation instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#BABGDJFH).

Comment: I now know where the location of the jdk is, so when i open the command prompt im presented with "C:\Users\My Name>" the whole command is.... "C:\Users\My Name> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac MyFirstProgram.java" it just returns 'C:\Program' is not recognised as an internal or external command ?!..im confused @assylias

Comment: @Treeno1 because the path has spaces, you need to put the command in quotes, like I did in my comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to fix this error in windows 10/8/7

1.Check your javac path on Windows using Windows Explorer C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin and copy the address.

2.Go to Control Panel. Environment Variables and Insert the address at the beginning of var. Path followed by semicolon. i.e C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin; . Do not delete the path existent, just click in and go to the left end and paste the line above. Do not try anything else, because you just need to link your code to "javac.exe" and you just need to locate it.

3.Close your command prompt and reopen it,and write the code for compile and execution.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the location of your JDK to your PATH variable, if you wish to call javac.exe without the path.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\your\JDK\bin\dir
```

Then...

```
javac.exe MyFirstProgram.java
```

OR, you can simply call it via the full path to javac.exe from your JDK installation e.g.

```
C:\path\to\your\JDK\bin\javac.exe MyFirstProgram.java
```